# Compatibility issue if two wordpress security plugins are used together

Tags: wordpress, waf

My Wordpress installation uses `sukuri` as well as `wordfence` for security. Is there any possibilty that using both of them together might create any compatibility issues?

I have this doubt because using two antivirus programs in a machine like windows usually creates issues which usually leads to improper working of both.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question title was misleading, because neither is what is usually understood as a "firewall". I edited it.

Comment: I would have recommended to migrate this question to https://wordpress.stackexchange.com but I just read that plugin problems are off-topic there.

Comment: I would like to strictly talk about security plugins and not about the others.